# ngFor does not trigger onChanges event in child components

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have this little example which I was paying with what I was trying to achive:

```
  <div *ngFor="let card of cards; let i = index">
    <app-card
      [card]="card"
      [index]="i"
      (cardClicked)="cardClicked($event)"
    ></app-card>
  </div>
```

After the cards array refreshes get a new value from a subject it does not input the new card values to the child components.

I have tried using async pipe and ChangeDetection ref.
Nothing seems to work.
Is this an anti pattern in angular?
Here is the full recreation of the issue:
https://github.com/ElesGergo/testangularrepo

Url: where the problem is /game/gameBoard/4

Flow:
Please check to console.

1. Parent component subscribes to the cards array behaviour subject in game service.
2. User click on 2 cards.(Child component)
3. Parent component recieves the values of the card data from child.
4. Parent component calls game service, which updates its behaviour subject and forwards the updated cardArray to the parent component.
5. Parent components rerenders its view and @inputs the updated values (eg.flipped) to each child component.

Comment: It's unclear from the provided snippet what you are trying to do, but the `OnChanges` lifecycle hook works with values received via `@Input()` from a parent component. Nothing you do inside the component is going to invoke that hook.

Comment: Please check to console.
0.Parent component subscribes to the cards array behaviour subject in game service.
1.User click on 2 cards.(Child component)
2.Parent component recieves the values of the card data from child.
3.Parent component calls game service, which updates its behaviour subject and forwards the updated cardArray to the parent component.
4.Parent components rerenders its view and @inputs the updated values (eg.flipped) to each child component.

Comment: I least share your components path. The best option is to share a stackblitz. It will be easier for us and also for you to explain.

Comment: module/game/components <----- card and card-board component
module/game/services <------ game service

Comment: Asking people to download, build and run your app in order to help you with your problem seems like a bit much, don't you think?

Comment: You can just not respond if you feel like  it takes too much time :)

Comment: I had similar issues before, when you update the array, change the location in memory. The `ngOnChanges` might not kick in because the location in memory of the array is the same. Make it like so when the array gets updated, `arrayGoingIntoChild = [...newArray.map((obj) => ({...obj}))]`.... The `...` in the array will make a copy in a new location in ram and `{...obj}` will make a new object in RAM if it is an array of objects.